# Change the MongoDB document date format in forEach loop

Tags: mongodb

I want to change the date format inside the find query. Below is my code which i am using. `TIME_STAMP` contains the date time.

```
db.bothistories.find( { "TIME_STAMP":{$gt:ISODate("2020-01-30T18:30:00Z"),
                                      $lt: ISODate("2020-01-31T18:30:59Z")}
                      }, 
                      { _id:0, CONVERSATION_ID:1, USER_ID:1, DATA_FROM_USER:1, DATA_FROM_HUMAN_AGENT:1, HUMAN_AGENT_ID:1, "DATA.text.body":1, TIME_STAMP:1, CHANNEL:1 } 
                     )
                     .sort({CONVERSATION_ID:-1,TIME_STAMP:1})
                     .forEach(function(myDoc) {
                      })
```

I want to use the function `{ $dateToString: { format: "%Y-%m-%d", date: "$date" } },` but don't know how to use inside select file format. I have tried the below

```
 "DATA.text.body":1,
 TIME_STAMP: { "format": "%Y-%m-%d", "date": "$TIME_STAMP" },
```

but it is not working.

Comment: [$dateToString](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/dateToString/) is an Aggregation query operator. You cannot use it in the `forEach` loop.

Comment: So how can I achieve this

Comment: You can write an aggregation query, with `$match` pipeline stage to do the filter, and a `$project` ( or `addFields`) stage to transform the date field and shape the document. Since, your query has a sort operation, you can do that using the `$sort` stage. You can build the aggregation query and run it from _Mongo Shell_, or if you have installed the _Mongo DB Compass_ GUI tool, the aggregation query can be built and run there too.